# Hiding a drive without Restarting the OS

Tags: windows-xp

I'm a college student.
As I've to share my PC with my friends I want to secure the laptop.
My plan is to hide a drive *[where I'm gonna store some important  document (not too much important that requires password) ]* without restarting the OS
Is it possible and how to do so ?

Comment: Why not create a TrueCrypt virtual drive and just mount it whenever you need too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `diskmgmt.msc` and remove a drive letter from the disk you want to hide. Drives without letters are not displayed in Explorer. To bring this "hidden" drive back, just re-assign desired letter

Comment: From command line, the same can be done with `mountvol`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get a [Passport](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=passport%20drive&tag=googhydr-20&index=electronics&hvadid=5796731107&ref=pd_sl_79fdmdv0k7_e)? Physically removing your data is way more secure than "hoping" they won't find a hidden drive/folder.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to "Uninstall" the drive in Device Manager, to get the drive to show back up you would need to scan for new hardware or install new hardware such as a USB device.  I would recommend the TrueCrypt solution, even though it is more security than you want in this case.